Trying to start Tunnelbear.exe in C#
So I need to programmatically start TunnelBear.exe (a VPN) in C#, and then kill it again. The command for this in cmd is (after going to the directory) TunnelBear.exe --on
This is what I tried in C#:
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\TunnelBear\TunnelBear.exe",
        Arguments = @"TunnelBear.exe --on",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    }
};
process.Start();


Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You have shown us the code but you didn't say what was working and what was not, try to update the question to be a little bit more specific

Why do you add the executable name in the arguments?
What happens and what do you expect?

Firstly, welcome to SO.
I think you are confusing the usage of ProcessStartInfo, you are specifying a FileName that should be started, and then passing to that application the full arguments with the Application Name.
Try changing the Argument to only `"--on", and seeing if that works?
Or alternatively change the UseShellExecute to true and then removing the FileName part and adding a Working Directory. Example:
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\TunnelBear",
        Arguments = @"TunnelBear.exe --on",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    }
};
process.Start();


Thanks for the suggestion! I tweaked a little, combining both your ideas and that did the trick thans.
